# How to use chekbox with Jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use checkbox with Ajax. Without Ajax I have handle it.
Here is my Jquery code

```
$("#skillcat").click(function(e) {
    var submit_val = new Array();
    e.preventDefault();
     var ids = $('check_subjects input:checked')
           .map(function(){
             return this.value;
           }).get();

    $.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data : {
        action : 'each_category',
        check_subjects : ids
    },
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);

        $('#accordion').html(data);


    }
    });
});
```

Here is my php code where button and checkbox is generated in serverside

```
foreach($subjects as $key=> $data){     
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'. $data->id .'" value="'. $data->id .'" name="check_subjects[]">&nbsp;&nbsp;  '. $data->subject .'<br>';
}
```

Serverside I used to catch data from Post array

```
if(isset($_POST['check_subjects'])){
    //var_dump(check_subjects);
    $check_subjects  = implode(',', $_POST['check_subjects']);
    //echo '$check_subjects&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $check_subjects;
}
```

however when I run above codes, I notice that some data is sent to the server(via chrom developer tool). But I get null in alert box. I guess response is null becase data is not sent to server properly. I am not sure about the javasript code I use to passe the request to Ajax.

Can anybody explain where I have done the mistake?

Comment: may be use `attr('checked')` instead of `.value` ?

Comment: @Prasanth prefer using `.val()` then or `prop('checked')`

Comment: I tried .val() but no luck.

Comment: Also, when you send data through POST to your server when you use the name="check_subjects[]" tag, it's already sent as an array.

Comment: you should print $check_subjects in your php file, as of now the php file is returning/printing nothing so the response is null.

Comment: It is expecting `JSON` and you are returning html. So make the dataType HTML or json encode your return...

Comment: `var ids = $('check_subjects input:checked')` what is check_subjects? Did you forget a `#`(id) or a `.`(class) in your jQuery selector?

Comment: check_subjects is the name of checkbox name, here I use check_box[] as name.

Comment: Use this for selecting your Checkboxes `$('[name*="check_subjects"]:checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#skillcat").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ids = [];
    var $el = $('[name*=check_subjects]:checked'); //Get all checked Checkboxes
    $el.each(function () {
        ids.push($(this).attr('id')); //get the Id from each checkbox
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'each_category',
            check_subjects: ids
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#accordion').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was not aware this syntax `$('[name*=check_subjects]:checked'); ` . How did you find this?

Answer (score 2):

It is expecting JSON and you are returning html. So make the dataType HTML or json encode your return...

Comment: `echo json_encode(array("success" => true, html => $html));` try that and remember to `header('Content-type: application/json');`. Your JS looks fine...